# How can I overcome this build error on deployment

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

This repository is working perfectly on local host, on deployment, it throwing build Failed errors on render.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khjZf.jpg)

I followed the documentation on how to deploy React app, which I have used for my previous apps.
Now it's throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have been able to resolve the issues of my build failing

I realized using css variable :root{--css-property:value;
}
Was the reason my run build was failing

I simply

include  the  css variables
In the body section  as

Body{--property:value}
And removed :root{}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).